# Async file upload (using FormData) with Node.JS Express and Formidable in the server side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, formidable

I want to upload files async to Node.JS Express.

I'm pretty confident with my HTML and Javascript because I've used them several times in the past with ASP.NET in the serverside.

Now I want to use the same clientside code with Node.JS with Express in the serverside.

HTML:

```
    <form id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>XML files (1 or many)</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="dummy" multiple ng-disabled="processing" accept=".xml" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="process()" ng-disabled="processing">
                <span ng-show="processing">Processing...</span>
                <span ng-show="!processing">Convert</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
        $scope.process = function () {
            $scope.processing = true;

            var formData = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('files').files.length; i++) {
                formData.append('file' + i, document.getElementById('files').files[i]);
            }

            var httpRequest = $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: "/api/parser/parse",
                data: formData,
                params: {
                },
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            });

            httpRequest.success(function (response) {
                $scope.response = response;

                if (response.error) {
                    toaster.pop('error', response.message);
                    return;
                }

                toaster.pop('success', "", "Finished processing");
            });

            httpRequest['finally'](function () {
                $scope.processing = false;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Serverside code (Node.JS):

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var _ = require('underscore');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/parse', function(req, res, next) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }

        console.log(files.length);  // Is outputting "undefined"
    });

    res.json({
        error: false
    });
});
```

How can I access the files being submitted?
As you can see, `console.log(files.length)` is giving me `undefined`

Comment: Did you try moving your `res.json()` to inside your `form.parse()` callback? The connection is probably being closed before the request data can be parsed.

Comment: ohhh, I will try... missed the fact that `form.parse()` is async!

Comment: It is throwing `undefined` anyways

Comment: Is there a reason why you are setting `'Content-Type': undefined` ? You should check the output of `console.dir(req.headers['content-type'])` and make sure it shows `multipart/form-data`.